# Firefox uses a different built-in stylesheet depending on the OS?

Tags: html, css, firefox

Here is a very simple HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.MyInputClass {position: absolute; left:32px; top:64px; width:119px; height:19px; padding: 0; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; font-size: 13px; text-align:left;}
.MySelectClass {position: absolute; left:159px; top:64px; width:121px; height:21px; padding: 0; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; font-size: 13px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input class="MyInputClass" type="TEXT" id="MyEdit">
<select class="MySelectClass" id="MySelect" ></select>
</body>
</html>
```

This is not the actual HTML I'm using, but it is for demonstration purposes.
Using ALL versions of FireFox (from 13.0 to 24.0) this is what I get (link to image on imgur.com):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc6Ph.jpg

Please note that under Windows 7, the visual height of INPUT and SELECT elements match, but under Windows XP, the height of the INPUT element is 2 pixels bigger than the SELECT.

Using Firebug, I could detect that Firefox is using a border-width = 2px under Windows XP and only 1px under Windows 7. I guess this comes from the built-in style sheet?

Also note that using something like a CSS reset, lets say:

```
<style type="text/css">
input {border-width: 1px;}
</style>
```

is not a viable solution, because whenever we set a border-width explicitly, the border drawing changes and we also get an inconsistent border:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Onqz.jpg

Please note that the bottom and right borders of the `input` element are almost invisible.

So, my questions are:

1. Is there any alternative for this, or I will be obligated to use some CSS reset script?
2. Why does Firefox have this inconsistent behavior?
3. If FF has different styles for different OSes, how can I be sure that my site or web application will render correctly in a future Windows, Mac or Linux version? (This seems quite impossible IMHO.)

I've also tested Chrome and Safari and they don't show this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Answers:

1. No alternative.
2. It's not inconsistent, every browser styles form elements slightly differently depending on the OS. The only thing that's consistent is that they are all inconsistent with each other.
3. You can't, but that's what web standards are for. Browser vendors do their best to implement the W3C spec so that as long as your code correctly conforms to the spec, you should be safe.

It's worth noting that form elements are very OS-specific, even more so select boxes (the damn things are absolutely impossible [literally, they're impossible] to style on a Mac).

If you need so much control over your form elements as to ensure they appear identical in every way, shape, and (pun coming) form, then you can't use form elements, you've got to build/find alternatives that are built in HTML/CSS/JS.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your answer. When I said "inconsistent" behavior of FF rendering is because other browsers (e.g. Chrome) use the same border-width in their built-in style sheet in all OSes. The same HTML in Chrome has a consistent look in every OS I've tested.

Comment: Have you tried `border-style` - some of them may use `inset`, others may use `outset`. If you want a consistent look, try `solid`

Comment: I will try to play with border-width/border-style settings. What annoys me (I'm not sure that my questions let it clear) is that under XP the INPUT is taller than the SELECT, but in Win7 they have exact the same heights. This way, there is no way to create perfect aligned controls (INPUT and SELECT) in both OS at the same time, without using some CSS reset, or setting border-width, and I repeat, only in Firefox. Even IE handle it better.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox uses whatever the OS-default theme is for form controls.  That will depend on the OS, on the OS version, on the theme the user has selected, and so forth.

That answers your question 2.  For question 1, I would suggest not worrying about it...  For question 3, you can't, unless your layout is robust to different appearances of the form controls.